# Duda sobre un botón en ARDUINO y PROCESSING para que se haga una acción una sola vez

Tags: imagen, botón, arduino, serialización, processing

estoy haciendo un proyecto donde hay una interacción entre Arduino y Processing gracais a dos botones y el serial. En el primer caso tengo el código de Arduino donde cada vez que se pulsa uno de los dos botones que hay, aparecerán un seguido de fotos en Processing (las fotos son CorBe y CorMal), si se pulsa el botón que esta en el pin 8 aparecerán en un loop la fotos **CorBe** y si se pulsa el del pin 9 aparecerán las de **CorMal**, estos son los primeros casos, los dos últimos casos de *if else* y *else*, son por si no se está pulsando el botón o por si se están pulsando los dos.

La cuestión es que necesito que solo pulsando el botón y aunque se mantenga pulsado éste, la imagen de CorBe o la de CorMal aparezca una vez, es decir cada vez que se pulsa el botón aparezca la imagen pero sin borrar las otras. ¿Tenéis alguna respuesta?

Os adjunto aquí los dos códigos:

-- Código Arduino:

```
int switchPin = 8;
int switchPinNou = 9;

void setup() {
//initialize serial communications at a 9600 baud rate
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){

  if (digitalRead(8) == HIGH && digitalRead(9) == LOW) {
    Serial.println("1");
  }

  else if (digitalRead(9) == HIGH && digitalRead(8) == LOW) {
    Serial.println("2");
  }

  else if (digitalRead(8) == HIGH  && digitalRead(9) == HIGH){
    Serial.println("3");
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("0");
    }
}
```

--- Código Processing:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;     // Data received from the serial port

PImage img;
PImage img2;
float value = 0;

void setup (){
 String portName = Serial.list()[0]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
 myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
 myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
  
 size(1920, 1080);
 background(0);
 img = loadImage("CorBe.png");
 img2 = loadImage("CorMal.png");

 //image(img, random(1900), random(1000), 50, 50);
 //image(img2, random(1900), random(1000), 50, 50);
}        

void draw (){
    while (myPort.available() > 0) {
     if (value == 1){
         println("detectado1");
         image(img, random(1900), random(1000), 50, 50);
       }   
     if (value == 2){
         println("detectado2");
         image(img2, random(1900), random(1000), 50, 50);
     }
    }
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
      value = float(myPort.readStringUntil('\n'));
    }
```

Comment: En Arduino tienes que leer sólo una vez el pin. Si lo lees dos veces, puede arrojarte resultados distintos. En cada iteración de `loop` deberias leer y guardar en variables ambos pines, y usar esas variables de ahi en adelante.

Comment: Al sketch le falta hacer *debouncing* de los botones. Cada vez que los presionas (o sueltas) se produce una ráfaga de HIGH-LOW en el pin antes de estabilizarse en uno de los dos valores. Esto produce un comportamiento aleatorio del programa.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas leyendo mal los botones en el Arduino.

Cuando presionas un botón, el evento dura mínimo 150ms. Durante todo ese tiempo, cada que leas el botón verás que está presionado y repetirás la acción.

Este ejemplo mostrará el problema.

```
int switchPin = 8;
int contador = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop(){

  if (digitalRead(8) == LOW) {
    contador++;
    Serial.print(contador);
    Serial.println(" 1");
  }
}
```

Nota: Use botón a tierra por comodidad; el único cambio es comparar contra LOW.

Este código produce

```
13:09:38.697 -> 1 1
13:09:38.697 -> 2 1
13:09:38.697 -> 3 1
13:09:38.697 -> 4 1
13:09:38.697 -> 5 1
13:09:38.697 -> 6 1
13:09:38.697 -> 7 1
13:09:38.730 -> 8 1
13:09:38.730 -> 9 1
13:09:38.730 -> 10 1
13:09:38.730 -> 11 1
13:09:38.730 -> 12 1
13:09:38.730 -> 13 1
13:09:38.763 -> 14 1
13:09:38.763 -> 15 1
13:09:38.763 -> 16 1
13:09:38.763 -> 17 1
13:09:38.763 -> 18 1
13:09:38.797 -> 19 1
13:09:38.797 -> 20 1
13:09:38.797 -> 21 1
13:09:38.797 -> 22 1
13:09:38.797 -> 23 1
13:09:38.830 -> 24 1
13:09:38.830 -> 25 1
13:09:38.830 -> 26 1
13:09:38.830 -> 27 1
13:09:38.830 -> 28 1
13:09:38.830 -> 29 1
13:09:38.830 -> 30 1
```

Cómo vez, una sola presión del botón generó 30 envios de "1" a Processing.

**Solución**

Debe hacer **debouncing** de los botones, de lo cual encontraras numeroso material y códigos en Internet.

Para fines demostrativos tenemos un algoritmo muy básico: después de ver que el pin ha cambiado, espera 250 ms antes de volver a leerlo. Si el usuario coopera un poco, no habrá duplicados:

```
int switchPin = 8;
unsigned long start_time = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {

  unsigned long now = millis();

  if (now - start_time > 250) {
    if (digitalRead(8) == LOW) {
      Serial.println("1");
      start_time = millis();
    }
  }
}
```

No usamos `delay` para esperar, simplemente anotamos el tiempo de la partida y en cada iteración de `loop` revisamos si ha pasado el tiempo correspondiente.